# How to apend the value of a button then change it back

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to add a directive to any button that replaces the button value with the word loading. Then somehow have a function which will revert the value of the button back when I call that function anywhere in my code  (say after ajax load).

I am wondering how this can be done in AngularJS.

First, I think I create a directive...

```
.directive('spinnerButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', clickedButton);

            function clickedButton() {
               //get button change  add the words loading...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

on my buttons as the directive...

```
  <div ng-click="loadsomething()" spinner-button>All Projects</div>
```

then somehow recall the drivetive to say revert back....

etc

```
.then(function (objects) {
                        //remove loading message

                    },
```

Comment: I think you'll need to add an `id` attribute to the DIV in order to reference it.  `<div id="btnLoadProject" ng-click etc></div>`.  Then use `getElementById()` to set the button text.  [Documentation for getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two way data binding for a `loading` property that is shared by the directive and the outer scope.  When you click the element, set `loading` to true.  Set `loading` to `false` in the outer scope (e.g. `loadsomething`) when the loading is done.

You can use transclusion to change what the button displays.

```
return {
    restrict: "A",
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div ng-transclude ng-hide=loading></div>"
        + "<img ng-show=loading src=throbber.gif>",
    scope: {loading: "=spinnerButton"},
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        elem.bind("click", function () { scope.loading = true; });
    }
};

<div ng-click="loadsomething()" spinner-button=loading>All Projects</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Loq0sm5w/